# $\sqrt{a^2 +(1-a)^2}+ \sqrt{b^2 +(1-b)^2} \geq \sqrt{2} $

Tags: inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima

$a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt:**

If i can prove that:
$$x^2 +(1-x)^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}$$
So therefore:
$$\sqrt{x^2 +(1-x)^2} \geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $$
But i can’t prove the first inequality .

Comment: Expand LHS and complete the square.

Comment: What happens if your add two inequalities which you can prove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not, square it and put everything on LHS, get rid of the denumerator.  You get $$(2x-1)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
 \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} \cdot \sqrt{x^2 + (1-x)^2} \ge 1\cdot x + 1 \cdot (1-x) = 1 \, .
$$

The geometric interpretation is that a point on the line $y=1-x$ in the 2D plane has at least the distance $1/\sqrt 2$ to the origin.

Yet another option is to substitute $x= \frac 12 + u$. Then
$$
 x^2 + (1-x)^2 = \left( \frac 12 + u\right)^2 + \left( \frac 12 - u\right)^2 = \frac 12 + 2 u^2 \ge \frac 12 \, .
$$

Comment: I like the simplicity of your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}$
$$=\sqrt{x^2+x^2-2x+1}$$
$$=\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}$$
This expression will be minimum if the thing inside the root is minimum.

Thus,
$$y=2x^2-2x+1$$
$$0=4x-2$$ $\text{"Differentiating both sides"}$
$$\implies x=\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus the function is minimum at $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Thus, minimum value of function is:$$2 \cdot(\frac{1}{2})^2-2 \cdot\frac{1}{2}+1$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}$$
Hence the minimum value of the expression $\sqrt{x^2+(1-x)^2}$ is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ $=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Thus the minimum value of $$\sqrt{a^2 +(1-a)^2}+ \sqrt{b^2 +(1-b)^2}$$ is : $$2 \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ $$=\sqrt{2}$$

Thus the required inequality has been proved.